# Will ModemManager v1.6 be a part of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, modem-manager

I'm using a Sierra MC7455 modem with Ubuntu 16.04 server, and would like to use this modem with raw IP. The latest version (16.04.2) has kernel 4.8 that support this, but modem manager ver 1.4.x does not. It must be version 1.6 or greater to support raw IP.

As far as I can read the forum I need ubuntu 16.10 or higher to get modem manager with raw IP support (which I have tested and it works with raw IP). My customer requires a LTS version of Ubuntu so I'm stuck with 16.04 for now.

Will Modem Manager be stepped up to 1.6 in later releases of 16.04.x or must I wait for 18.04 LTS to get raw IP support? If so, what is the easiest way to cherry pick modem manager package from Ubuntu 16.10 and install it in 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this PPA, which provides MM 1.6.x for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:
https://launchpad.net/~aleksander-m/+archive/ubuntu/modemmanager-xenial